# Can I get MySQL field list of same key row?

Tags: mysql

```
Original Table A

sid pos uuid  acc
1    1   k1   9.1
2    1   k2   10.5
3    1   k3   8.3
4    2   k2   10.4
5    2   k1   7.2
6    2   k3   10.1
7    2   k3   6.2
8    2   k1   10.3
9    2   k2   9.4


into 


pos acc1(k1) acc2(k2) acc3(k3)
1    9.1      10.5      8.3
2    7.2      10.4     10.1
2    10.3     9.4       6.2



I've been googling for a week, I couldn't find solution...
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

MySQL please!
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pivot query:

```
SELECT pos,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uuid = 'k1' THEN acc END) AS `acc1(k1)`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uuid = 'k2' THEN acc END) AS `acc2(k2)`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN uuid = 'k3' THEN acc END) AS `acc3(k3)`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY pos, (sid-1) DIV 3
ORDER BY pos
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I've checked the most of the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: The result is not what I expected!

Comment: @KihyeonKwon I just gave you an edit which should work, at least for your exact data set.

Comment: Thank for your answer and espacially using the SQLFiddle. I've checked your solution.